# looking for a sample code for springboot, activemq(topic)

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jms-topic

i found many code samples to create a JMS queue project but didn't find code sample for activemq( topic) which is called as PUB-SUB(Publisher-Subscriber).

for Spring i found below code but am looking for spring boot complete code .

```
       Topic topic = topicConsumerSession.createTopic("customerTopic");

        // Consumer1 subscribes to customerTopic
        MessageConsumer consumer1 = topicConsumerSession.createSubscriber(topic);
        consumer1.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener(
                "Consumer1"));

        // Consumer2 subscribes to customerTopic
        MessageConsumer consumer2 = topicConsumerSession.createSubscriber(topic);
        consumer2.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener(
                "Consumer2"));
```

**Big Thanks to @Gary Russell first of all.**

## this is what i have implemented from @Gary Russell suggestions. is there any good practice for separation of concerns and more scalable way.

### application.properties

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
#spring.jms.template.default-destination=testTopic
```

### Publisher.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Publisher implements CommandLineRunner{
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate ;
@Autowired
private Topic topic1;
@Autowired
private Topic topic2;

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread.sleep(5000); // wait for subscriptions, unless they are durable
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic1,"-----> 1st message from publisher -- topic 1");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic1,"-----> 2nd message from publisher -- topic 1");
    /**
     * for topic2 
     */

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread.sleep(5000); // wait for subscriptions, unless they are durable
         this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic2,"-----> 1st message from publisher -- topic 2");
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic2,"-----> 2nd message from publisher -- topic 2");

}
}
```

### Subscriber.java

```
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class Subscriber {
@JmsListener(destination = "Topic1")
public void listener1(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener1: " + in);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "Topic1,Topic2")
public void listener2(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener2: " + in);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "Topic2")
public void listener3(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener3: " + in+"\n listener 3 is just ");
}
}
```

mainclass : springBootApplication

### PubSubJmsBootApplication.java

```
import javax.jms.Topic;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class PubSubJmsBootApplication {


    @Bean
    public Topic topic1() {
        return new ActiveMQTopic("Topic1");
    }
    @Bean
    public Topic topic2() {
        return new ActiveMQTopic("Topic2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PubSubJmsBootApplication.class, args);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

[you can find spring-boot samples here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples)

Comment: seen that already , it doesn't have activemq( topic) which is called as PUB-SUB(Publisher-Subscriber).

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties`.

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
spring.jms.template.default-destination=testTopic
```

Then...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42173236Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So42173236Application.class, args)
            .close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // wait for subscriptions, unless they are durable
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("foo");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "testTopic")
    public void listener1(String in) {
        System.out.println("Listener1: " + in);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "testTopic")
    public void listener2(String in) {
        System.out.println("Listener2: " + in);
    }

}
```

If you build the `JmsTemplate` or listener container yourself (rather than using Boot's auto configuration), just `setPubSubDomain(true)`.

Comment: what if i want to create a new topic .
is it a right way ==> 
'
    spring.jms.template.default-destination=youtube-channel

Comment: Yes; the topic will be created if it doesn't exist. You can also specify the destination (topic name) in the `convertAndSend` command. The key is that the template is configured for pub/sub.

Comment: why do you have 'spring.jms.template.default-destination=testTopic' property when you overwrite this with '@JmsListener(destination = "testTopic")'?

Comment: ? The template is used for sending, the listener is receiving. `this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("foo");` sends `foo` to the default destination.

Comment: It says 'Default destination to use on send and receive operations that do not have a destination parameter.'
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Comment: Right, but the template is not used for receive operations here (`template.receive()`). The `@JmsListener` uses a listener container instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can find some easy code in this repo [spring-boot-quick](https://github.com/vector4wang/spring-boot-quick)

https://github.com/vector4wang/spring-boot-quick/tree/master/quick-activemq
https://github.com/vector4wang/spring-boot-quick/tree/master/quick-activemq2

If you have a lot of news queues and a lot of msg, such as a few million, it is best not to use activemq. I use it in the production environment here, and I am pitted. I need to fill in all kinds of pits. You can use RabbitMQ